# How do I access a property created in global.asax.cs?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm reading two values from the web.config in the `Application_Start` of my `Global.asax.cs`. The string values from the web.config are assigned to their public properties, also defined in the Global.asax.cs .

How do I access the properties in the global.asax.cs file from another class, method, and namespace?

Update #1
This is more complicated than I thought (or maybe I'm just making it complicated). The class where I want to reference these properties in a plain ol' class library and I don't have access to httpcontext (or I don't know how to access it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Global.asax.cs doesn't manipulate the values, then simply read the values from the web.config like you already do in global.asax.cs.

However, if the Global.asax.cs does manipulate the values, then you could write the values into the "Application" object.

```
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup

        Application.Add("Foo", "Bar");

    }
```

Lastly, you can mark the property you want to expose from the Global as static.

```
    public static string Abc { get; set; }
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup

        Abc = "123";

    }
```

Comment: I thought about reading the values directly from the config file, as I do in the global.asax.cs. The problem is this would be read many, many times and, to me, it makes more sense to read it once, store it in a variable, and reference the variable when needed. We're using EF and this event handler (where the value is needed) gets fired alot so there would be a whole lot of reading from the web.config.

Answer (score 5):

Cast the current application instance to your `Global` type and access the properties there.

```
var app = (Your.App.Namespace.Global)HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance;
var x = app.YourProperty;
```

Comment: @Greg_B It would actually be HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance as HttpContext.Current.Application is an HttpApplicationState object not an HttpApplication object.